# What reason could a company have for preventing users from changing their passwords

Tags: windows, security-policy

If a user wants to change their password they have to either let the IT department generate a random one or else they have to tell them the new password over the phone.  Either way the IT department apparently needs to know what the password is (where they store this information is unknown).

The IT department claims this is company policy but I don't see the point.  It's not like users can do anything to lock the company out.

In fact I feel like this makes things less secure since the inconvenient process makes it less likely a busy IT department is going to periodically call users to perform a password change.

Comment: that is an odd policy. I have to assume that they create multiple accounts on multiple systems that don't talk to eachother (like an old mainframe or whatever where noone but an over-privledged admin can change passowrds).

Comment: I used to work for a company that not only prevented users from changing email passwords but also made them all the _same_ (only 6 characters and very easy to guess). I finally managed to convince them to let me reset everyone's passwords after one account got compromised and used to send spam floods. Luckily the spammer never realized what a vein of gold was sitting just below the nugget of one account.

Comment: "What reason could a company have for preventing users from changing their passwords" - Why does your company require IT to change it?  Why don't you ask them?  Ask to see the policy, the reason, likely is explained.

Answer (score 0):

I know of only one reason, and that is from a horror story where an auditor required IT to present all users passwords.

Other than someone blindly following that horror screnario (instead of declaring the auditor horrible incompetent) there is not single reason why this ever would be a good idea.

Just to make this a bit more explicit:

- There is no reason to tell your password(s) to anyone. This includes IT people. They may ask you to log in (and you enter the password while they do not look at your keyboard) to help troubleshoot issues, but they should never ever ask for a password.
- Access to shared resources (e.g. a coworker leaving work) should do done carefully. The solution is not to get another users password but the rights to access the needed data. (once again, *NEVER* share a password).
- Never tell a password to anyone on the phone.
  ...
  I guess I could go on, but there is no single reason for anyone to ever have your password at work. None. Nada. Zip. Zilch. Rien.

Good, now that is out of the way, ypur title was: "What reason could a company have for preventing users from changing their passwords". I can think of no sane reason for that either. In fact, someone has to generate an initial password. If you cannot change the password without telling it you would need to go to the IT office, ask them to look away or leave the room and type in your initial password. You would also need to repeat this yearly (or more often if you expect someone might have seen you type the password).

All in all it is utterly insane.

Answer (score 0):

There can be partial reasons for this odd policy. Sometimes the network of systems need the password change to originate at one server and propagate to the rest.  This can happen if there is a mixture such as Microsoft and Linux servers that have their own security/audit trail.  This has a lot of long term problems, but yes you can have changes must occur in IT. It took the team in charge of the central password server to get things working over a year.  Not sure why it took them so long.

I have seen really odd things from the other side of IT. This can be legal, the result of customer contracts, or other limitation that may force IT to have this setup.  Sometimes, IT gets told you may not tell the reason why this bad setup is being used.  Most HR rules have in them, a do not share password component.

The last I have seen is when an Exec wants to know everyone's password, or have a monitoring program that needs everyone's password.  I explained this was not going to happen. I got backed up by a higher exec, otherwise....